# How to hide el-form-item__error after field valid?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vee-validate, element-plus

vue `3.2.31`

vee-validate `4.5.10`

element-plus `2.1.6`

On input event, it shows validation error message properly. But on blur event, it shows `is required` error message. Also on blur event, even if validation succeeded, it shows `is required` error message. But when form valid, `meta.valid` is true and vice versa.

[image]

On that time console like follows:

[image]

My code:

```
<VeeForm v-slot="{ isSubmitting, meta }" @submit="submitForm" ref="loginFormObserver" as="div">    
        <el-form :model="loginForm" ref="loginForm" name="loginForm" size="small" label-position="left" label-width="30%">    
            <VeeField :rules="'required|email'" name="Username" v-slot="{ field, errorMessage }">    
                <el-form-item :error="errorMessage" label="Username" required>    
                    <el-input v-model="loginForm.username" type="email" clearable status-icon v-bind="field">
                    </el-input>    
                </el-form-item>    
            </VeeField>    
            <el-form-item class="text-center">    
                <el-button class="login-btn" native-type="submit" type="primary" :disabled="!meta.valid || isSubmitting">{{ trans('common.login') }} </el-button>    
            </el-form-item>    
        </el-form>    
    </VeeForm>
```

If I avoid `required` attribute from`el-form-item`, it works properly. But it removes red asterisk (star) beside labels of required fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be element-plus validation causing the confusion. You can disable their validation with: `:validate-event="false"`. Which should give you the asterisk and remove the validation behavior from element-plus.

```
<el-input v-model="loginForm.username" type="email" clearable status-icon v-bind="field" :validate-event="false"></el-input>
```

Comment: <el-checkbox-group v-model="loginForm.checkbox" v-bind="field" :validate-event="false"></el-checkbox-group>
There is not able to disable validation